# App Engine, query results displayed locally, but not on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working with App Engine, and my problem is that query results don't show up when deployed to App Engine. However everything works fine locally.

I'm using the App Engine Datastore to store query results. Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is there in the cloud Datastore? If you add data when running your webapp locally, that data would be added only to the local Datastore. When the webapp runs in the cloud, it reads only from the cloud Datastore.

Comment: Check the datastore viewer in production to see if you actually have any data.  ALso check the logviewer for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have indexed (and created composite indexes where necessary) for the fields in use in your query. The deployed appengine requires these to exist, but locally it will prompt you to add a composite index on first usage and work fine thereafter.